# Wikidata SPARQL Property Paths: asterisk and plus - wdt:P40+ vs wdt:P40/wdt:P40*

Tags: sparql, wikidata

It seems that `wdt:P40+` is not exactly the same as `wdt:P40/wdt:P40*`.

Example:

```
SELECT ?ancetre ?ancetreLabel
WHERE
{
  ?ancetre wdt:P40+ wd:Q346
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

It returns 852 results. (10 June 2019)

```
SELECT ?ancetre ?ancetreLabel
WHERE
{
  ?ancetre wdt:P40/wdt:P40* wd:Q346
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

The last returns 1046 results. (10 June 2019, same date as above)

I would expects the same results for both queries

Could someone explains this ?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found an explanation: 
`wdt:P40/wdt:P40*` can get more result because of duplicate.
So if we replace `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT`, there is no more difference between the queries.